# How to properly implement FromJSON for my data type?

Tags: json, haskell

I have a data with a few constructors:

```
data MyData = 
  A1 { var1 :: Int, var2 :: String }
  A2 { var1 :: Int, var2 :: String, var3 :: Char }
  A3 { var1 :: Int, var2 :: Char, var3 :: String, var4 :: String }
```

This is a simplified version of my real "data".  Without using `deriving (Generic)`, how can I implement it for the class `ToJSON`?

```
instance FromJSON MyData where
  parseJSON (Object v) = do
    .. --- how do I know if v is created by A1 or A2 or A3?
```

Comment: That's not a valid `data` type. Did you miss some `|`?

Comment: You ask about ToJSON then show FromJSON... are you wanting both?

Answer (score 2):

Aeson's `Parser` is an instance of [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative). As such, you can provide multiple parsers and combine them with `(<|>)`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Data.Aeson

-- Removed record fields to keep things short, but you can put them back.
data MyData = A1 Int String
            | A2 Int String Char
            | A3 Int Char   String String
            deriving Show

instance FromJSON MyData where
  parseJSON (Object v) =  A3 <$> v .: "var1" <*> v .: "var2" <*> v .: "var3" <*> v .: "var4" 
                      <|> A2 <$> v .: "var1" <*> v .: "var2" <*> v .: "var3"
                      <|> A1 <$> v .: "var1" <*> v .: "var2"
```

Note that the order of parsers is important, since `v .: "var1"` and `v .: "var2"` succeed for all three parsers.